# MySQL to PostgreSQL query alias GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, alias

I have a table that looks like this

```
id   |   number
---------------
1       56721
2       56722
3       43981
4       43982
5       43983 
6       43984
```

My MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT CASE substr(number,1,2) WHEN '56' then 'class1' WHEN '43' then 'class2' else 'other' END as class, 
       CASE substr(number,3,2) WHEN '72' then 'subclass1', WHEN '98' then 'subclass2' ELSE 'other' END as subclass, count(id) as ct 
FROM table GROUP BY class, subclass HAVING class!='other' AND subclass!='other' 
ORDER BY class ASC, subclass DESC;
```

What is the corresponding PostgreSQL query for this?

Answer (score 2):

To make it more clearer, wrap it on a subquery:

```
SELECT  class, subclass
FROM
    (
        SELECT  CASE substr(number,1,2) WHEN '56' then 'class1' WHEN '43' then 'class2' else 'other' END as class, 
                CASE substr(number,3,2) WHEN '72' then 'subclass1', WHEN '98' then 'subclass2' ELSE 'other' END as subclass 
        FROM    table 
    ) x
GROUP   BY class, subclass 
HAVING  class != 'other' AND subclass != other 
ORDER   BY class ASC, subclass DESC;
```

Comment: For your answer PostgreSQL give me an error like  "column "table.number" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: @Revan Did you get that error with the current  answer or from a previous version? Because I don't see how it could happen with the current one.

Answer (score 0):

If `number` is actually stored as a number (which makes sense to me), then you need to deal with type conversions.  MySQL supports `substr()` on numeric values, but not Postgres:

```
SELECT class, subclass, count(*)
FROM (SELECT  (CASE substr(numstr,1,2) WHEN '56' then 'class1'
                                       WHEN '43' then 'class2'
                                       else 'other'
               END) as class, 
              (CASE substr(numstr,3,2) WHEN '72' then 'subclass1'
                                       WHEN '98' then 'subclass2'
                                       ELSE 'other'
               END) as subclass
        FROM (select t.*, cast(number as varchar(255)) as numstr
              from table t
             ) t
    ) t
WHERE class <> 'other' AND subclass <> 'other'
GROUP BY class, subclass 
ORDER BY class ASC, subclass DESC;
```

I also changed the comparison in the `having` clause to `subclass <> 'other'`.  There is no column called `other`, so I assume you mean the value.

Comment: For your answer PostgreSQL give me an error like "column "table.numstr" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: @RevanDarth . . . That makes no sense at all.  Do you have a `count(*)` on one of the subqueries?  It should only appear on the outer query.